# relation between light intensity and R,G,B

Tags: c, graphics

I have a one ambient light with intesity ( 10000,10000, 5000 ). I am trying to color the primitive.

As you know, color values for R,G, and B are between 0 and 255. How can I find color of the pixel according to light intesity ?

platform : linux and programming language c

EDIT :

In ray tracer, we are calculating

```
for each ambient light in the environment
 color . R  += Intensity of the light * ambient coefficient for color R
 color . G  += Intensity of the light * ambient coefficient for color G
 color . B  += Intensity of the light * ambient coefficient for color B
```

However, whenever I have tried to emit this pixel color value on the screen with openGL.

`set pixel color ( color )`

I have taken wrong color because of intensity is high and maximum color value is low.

Comment: Your question makes no sense as written.  What do you mean by "color"? what is the range of the intensity values?

Comment: @Alnitak please look edit. If still unclear, please say

Comment: you need to specify the colorspace, otherwise the question does not make sense

Comment: What is the colorspace ?

Comment: Also, you may review articles on Wikipedia: [HSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Lightness) and [L*a*b](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L*a*b*), there are various maths to do the job.

Comment: @OttavioCampana the colorspace is RGB...

Comment: I am trying to edit as much as possible. Why did user downvote my question without giving any comment ?

Comment: ok, so, the part that I don't understand is "light with intesity (10000,10000, 5000)". What's the upper limit? What's the colorspace?

Comment: @OttavioCampana the colourspace is RGB.  The upper limit doesn't matter - what matters is what is the _nominal_ limit.  On most renderers its `[0..1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, as written, so here's some general advice.

Colours in renderers are typically held as values with a nominal range of [0..1] for each of the RGB components.

When those colours are rendered to pixels, they're usually just multiplied by 255 to give a 24-bit colour value (8 bits per component).

If the original values are *outside* of the [0..1] range they **must** be "clamped" so that the resulting pixel values fall in the [0..255] range.

That clamping can either be done "per component", which in your case would result in (255, 255, 255), or each component could be divided by the maximum component, giving (255, 255, 127) - i.e. preserving their relative intensities in pseudo-code:

```
float scale = max(r, g, b);
if (scale < 1) {
    scale = 1;     // don't normalise colours that are "in range"
}

byte R = 255 * (r < 0 ? 0 : r / scale);
byte G = 255 * (g < 0 ? 0 : g / scale);
byte B = 255 * (b < 0 ? 0 : b / scale);
```

It's usual for all *intermediate* calculations to preserve the full dynamic range of intensities.  For example, it wouldn't make sense for the Sun to have a brightness of "1", since every other object in the scene would by comparison have an almost infinitesimally small value.

The net result of the clamping will therefore be that light sources which contribute too much light to the scene will produce "saturation" of the image - i.e. the same effect that you get if you leave the shutter open too long on a picture of a bright scene.

Comment: Can you explain clamping more ?

Comment: Not really - read my updated answer, it should explain what you need.  Note that ambient values of 10000 would be considered _very_ high in any normally rendered.  Why have you picked those values?

Comment: It is text exercise. I have not chosed these value.

Answer (score 1):

It's this one you want: 
brightness  =  sqrt( .241*R*R + .691*G*G + .068*B*B )

Find more here: http://www.nbdtech.com/Blog/archive/2008/04/27/Calculating-the-Perceived-Brightness-of-a-Color.aspx

or here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminance_(relative)

Comment: what is the .241, .691, and .068 ? Is they ambient coeficient for each color

Comment: They are the cooefficients used to correct for the human eye's different response to each of the 3 colours. They're what you use to correctly greyscale an image based on it's (human) perceived brightness.

Comment: @user1783508 they're standard values for the _relative_ contribution of the RGB components into a gray-scale "colour" that has the same perceived brightness.  The eye is most sensitive to green, hence why its coefficient is higher.  It's irrelevant for this question, as far as I can see.